# Do People need gravity for extended stays in space?

Tags: science-based, biology, space

What are the physiological effects on a human being in a zero G environment for an extended period of time? I am aware that astronauts lose some bone density after missions to the ISS (which I believe are usually 6 month trips) however I am curious if the amount of bone density loss is proportional to the amount of time spent in space.

If John was in space for 6 months and lost 1 unit of bone density, then would John lose 2 units across 12 months, for example?

Comment: you have only touched the tip of all the messed up things that happen to the human body in microgravity. Swelling, bloating, blood production decrease, sleep loss, inability to balance, blindness... https://www.nasa.gov/hrp/bodyinspace

Comment: Or [Wiki: Effect of spaceflight on the human body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_of_spaceflight_on_the_human_body).  This question is off-topic because there are plenty of answers via google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks basic research.

Comment: There were two questions in the original. One was about the effects of space travel, the other about ways to prevent or treat. Those should be separate questions, so I deleted the second one. I think that his is appropriately scoped  and on-topic now. Knowing the effects of space travel is pretty crucial to building a hard sci-fi future.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of treatment, any form of exercise tends to slow the loss of muscle/bone mass. I assume the ideal way would be to eventually create artificial gravity for a station. Your body will not atrophy if it is under approriate stress.

In regards to the speed of loss, you may see a sort of "grace period" where the loss is minimal before it accelerates, as the body tends to have some inertia. I can't say it would continue to accelerate once the decay actually began, but what I can say is, at some point, the decay could be bad enough that you would reduce using that limb even more, further exacerbating the issue.

Ex. You hurt your leg, you stop using it. When it stops being used, it decays. By the time it "heals", its so weak that using it is uncomfortable. It will decay to useless levels at this stage if action is not taken.

The same thing could conceivably happen to astronauts. If you injure your leg, you won' be using it to boost yourself around the station. Eventually you're doing all the boosting with your arms.

Comment: But should muscle and bone mass loss occur, is there anyway to fix it after its happened?

Comment: That is somewhat outside my knowledge, but I would venture that it would be similar to physical therapy. Exercise, exercise, vitamins and steroids potentially if it was bad enough. Its obviously MUCH easier to prevent than to repair.